# Удалить из массива повторяющиеся значения

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как из такого массива избавиться от повторяющихся значений?

```
Array
(
    [status] => false
    [message] => Array
        (
            [0] => Поля не могут быть пустыми
            [1] => Поля не могут быть пустыми
            [2] => Поля не могут быть пустыми
            [3] => Поля не могут быть пустыми
            [4] => Некорректный E-mail
        )

    [inpnames] => Array
        (
            [0] => ulogin
            [1] => uemail
            [2] => upwd
            [3] => upwd_rpt
            [4] => uemail
        )

)
```

Убрать нужно только из подмассива `message`. Понимаю, что нужно через `foreach` обойти, по пока не додумался. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А почему бы просто не добавлять в массив уже существующие значения, нежели потом избавляться от них?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Понимаю, что нужно через foreach обойти, по пока не додумался. Заранее благодарю.

Это не единственный путь. Можно воспользоваться встроенной фунцией `array_unique()`:

```php
$array['message'] = array_unique($array['message']);
```

[Документация.](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php)

P.S. По личному опыту - полезно регулярно гуглить запрос типа `php array functions` или `php string functions`. "Освежение" знание встроенных функций часто приводит к нахождению весьма эффективных и неожиданных решений.

Comment: Согласен с автором. Есть ещё порядка 7-9 вариантов удаления одинаковых значений в массиве, но это специальная функция php, которая на это и ориентирована. И работает она быстрее.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы. я пытался использовать эту функцию на весь свой массив и естественно у меня ничего не вышло. но ведь мне ничего не мешает до его вывода, использовать array_unique на нужный мне подмассив message. что-то я до этого не додумался... благодарю еще раз)